# Python Won't Run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8035g.png)I was practicing some skills for data science and wanted to try out this project involving food reviews and web scraping (on Python3). This is the code for it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Used headers/agent because the request was timed out and asking for an agent.
#Using following code we can fake the agent.
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/top-restaurants",headers=headers)

content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

top_rest = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "bb0 collections-grid col-l-16"})
list_tr = top_rest[0].find_all("div",attrs={"class": "col-s-8 col-l-1by3"})

list_rest =[]
for tr in list_tr:
    dataframe ={}
    dataframe["rest_name"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "res_title zblack bold nowrap"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    dataframe["rest_address"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class": "nowrap grey-text fontsize5 ttupper"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    dataframe["cuisine_type"] = (tr.find("div",attrs={"class":"nowrap grey-text"})).text.replace('\n', ' ')
    list_rest.append(dataframe)
list_rest

import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(list_rest)
df.to_csv("zomato_res.csv",index=False)
```

The issue is when I try running it on my OSX Terminal, it just gives me a blank. I think it's supposed to create a CSV file, but I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of the terminal while this is running?

Comment: added! Sorry I'm kind of new at this but I think adding the screenshot worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot use CSS class names here - they are changing often. To get data about the restaurants, use following example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}
response = requests.get(
    "https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/top-restaurants",
    headers=headers,
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

sections = soup.find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "section"
    and [t.name for t in tag.find_all(recursive=False)] == ["a", "div"]
)

list_rest = []
for section in sections:
    name = section.img["alt"]
    addr = section.find("a", color=True)
    typ = [a.text for a in addr.find_next("div").find_all("a")]
    list_rest.append(
        {
            "rest_name": name,
            "rest_address": addr.text,
            "cuisine_type": ", ".join(typ),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(list_rest)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                      rest_name           rest_address                                       cuisine_type
0                    Chaat King   Rajarajeshwari Nagar      Quick Bites, Street Food, Sandwich, Fast Food
1                        Onesta        Electronic City  Casual Dining, Café, Pizza, Fast Food, Dessert...
2              Nammura Upachara     Basaveshwara Nagar  Quick Bites, South Indian, North Indian, Stree...
3                Bakasura Bandi             Nagarbhavi       Quick Bites, Fast Food, Chinese, Street Food
4       New Punjabi Food Corner        Electronic City               Casual Dining, North Indian, Chinese
5                        Noon's                    HSR                               Quick Bites, Biryani
6             New Malabar Hotel           New BEL Road  Quick Bites, Chinese, South Indian, Rolls, Nor...
7                         Sagar          Seshadripuram  Casual Dining, North Indian, Street Food, Fast...
8               Amma's Pastries             Nagarbhavi                           Bakery, Bakery, Desserts
9          Shawarma Grill House            Rajajinagar             Quick Bites, Chinese, Biryani, Mughlai
10             One For The Road             Whitefield                       Bar, North Indian, Fast Food
11                  Gawky Goose       Old Airport Road  Bar, Casual Dining, Italian, South Indian, Nor...
12  Byg Brewski Brewing Company                 Hennur  Microbrewery, Continental, North Indian, Itali...
13             The Bier Library  Koramangala 6th Block  Microbrewery, Continental, North Indian, Pizza...
14                    Just Cake            Magadi Road  Bakery, Bakery, Desserts, Street Food, Fast Fo...
15            New Shanthi Sagar            Rajajinagar  Quick Bites, Chinese, Street Food, North India...
16               Chichaba's Taj            Frazer Town     Casual Dining, North Indian, Chinese, Desserts
17               Bucket Biryani           Brigade Road                      Casual Dining, Biryani, Kebab
18              Razakhiya Hotel             HBR Layout  Quick Bites, Rolls, Chinese, North Indian, Sea...
19                 Sai Cafe Veg           Malleshwaram                             Quick Bites, Fast Food
20                     Parkview               JP Nagar  Quick Bites, South Indian, North Indian, Stree...
21                  Grill House   Rajarajeshwari Nagar         Quick Bites, North Indian, Chinese, Andhra
22          Goli Vada Pav No. 1             Nagarbhavi                Quick Bites, Street Food, Fast Food
23           Savoury Restaurant            Frazer Town  Quick Bites, Arabian, Mughlai, North Indian, C...
24     Chaayos - Meri Wali Chai           Malleshwaram  Café, Cafe, Tea, Street Food, Fast Food, Bever...
25                        SMOOR      Bannerghatta Road        Dessert Parlor, Desserts, Cafe, Pizza, Thai
26              SLAY Coffee Bar  Koramangala 5th Block                 Café, Coffee, Fast Food, Beverages
27           Indiranagar Social            Indiranagar  Bar, Café, North Indian, Chinese, Burger, Momo...
28   Third Wave Coffee Roasters               JP Nagar            Café, Cafe, Coffee, Fast Food, Desserts
29                       Aubree                MG Road     Bakery, Cafe, Bakery, Fast Food, Italian, Thai
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]